# Directional derivative of $xe^y+y\sin(x)$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I'm trying to calculate the directional derivative of $f(x,y) = xe^y+y\sin(x)$ at the points $(0,1), (1,2)$ and $(2,1)$ in the directions $(-1, 0)$ and $(2,3)$. Should I do each point and direction separately? As in

$\nabla f(x,y) = (e^y+y\cos{x}, xe^{y}+\sin{x})$ so $\nabla f(x,y) \cdot (-1,0) = -e^{y}-y\cos{x} \therefore \nabla f(0,1)\cdot(-1,0) =-1.$

Is this correct?

Comment: Looks fine. Just note that $(2,3)$ may require normalisation, depending on the definition of the directional derivative you are using.